# Can't update menu item state in ViewPager during swiping

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewpager, androidimageslider

I have favourite icon in my menu and the `ViewPager`. When I click to item, it changes. But when I swiping, It does not remember the state of item.

I have implemented `setOnPageChangeListener` and in `onPageSelected` checked the state of item and changed drawables.

```
override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {

                currentPage = position
                if (imageModelArrayList!![currentPage].isFavourite == true) {
                    isExistInFavorite = true

                    menuItem?.icon =
                        ContextCompat.getDrawable(
                            applicationContext,
                            R.drawable.ic_favorite_black_24dp
                        )

                   helper.updateGreetingByID(true, id)

                } else {
                    isExistInFavorite = false
                    menuItem?.icon =
                        ContextCompat.getDrawable(
                            applicationContext,
                            R.drawable.ic_favorite_border_black_24dp
                        )
                    helper.updateGreetingByID(false, id)
                }

            }
```

Here is item click

R.id.action_favorite -> {

```
            if (!isExistInFavorite) {
                greetingModel.id?.let { helper.updateGreetingByID(true, id) }
                menuItem?.icon =
                    ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_favorite_black_24dp)
                Toast.makeText(
                    this@ImageDetailActivity,
                    "Favourite added",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
                isExistInFavorite = true

            } else {
                isExistInFavorite = false
                menuItem?.icon =
                    ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_favorite_border_black_24dp)
                Toast.makeText(
                    this@ImageDetailActivity,
                    "favourite deleted",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
                greetingModel.id?.let { helper.updateGreetingByID(false, id) }
            }

            return true
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to call [invalidateOptionsMenu()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#invalidateOptionsMenu()) after changing the icon.